# executing a stored procedure in sql server 2008 with four events

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My question is how can I execute a particular stored  procedure. When I execute a particular event it gives me an error:

> Procedure or function 'StoredProcedureNames' expects parameter '@empid', which was not supplied

How do I supply it? My SQL is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE StoredProcedureNames
@event tinyint,
@empid int,
@emp_name varchar(50),
@emp_phno char(10),
@emp_add nvarchar(75)

AS

IF @event  = 1
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO employee_test (emp_name,emp_phno,emp_add,empid )
  VALUES (@emp_name,@emp_phno,@emp_add,@empid) 
END

ELSE IF @event  = 2
BEGIN
  UPDATE employee_test SET 
    emp_name = @emp_name,
    emp_phno = @emp_phno,
    emp_add = @emp_add,
    empid = @empid 
  WHERE (emp_Add = @emp_add
         and emp_name = @emp_name
         and emp_phno = @emp_phno
         and empid = @empid )
END

ELSE IF @event = 3
BEGIN
  select empid,emp_phno  from employee_test
  where (emp_Add = @emp_add or emp_name = @emp_name ) -- when i execute any event say exex sp 3 it shows a error
END 

ELSE IF @event = 4
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM employee_test
  WHERE (emp_phno = @emp_phno or emp_name = @emp_name )
End
```

The error it shows when i m not supply all field values as

> Error converting data type varchar to int.

what does it mean?

Comment: How are you executing the stored procedure? Sounds like you are not supplying enough parameters and the one you are missing is being interpreted for another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no defaults on the parameters for one so you must specify them all.

This should be done with a SQLParameters collections attached to a SQLCommand. This will generate a "namef parameter" call where it lists them in the comamnd sent to SQL Server

In your case, you are missing the parameter because you are using string concatenation and/or you have no defaults. The error about conversion comes from, say, `@emp_name` in the place of `@emp_id`

Anyway, it's hard to know exactly because we don't know how you call this code